# Adding line breaks in a TextView on a string received from a server as JSON response

Tags: android

```
val desc = /* String Rec From Server ("one line \n two line") */
product_description?.text = desc
```

I want the Text view to be

```
one line
two line
```

But i am getting it as

```
one line \n two line
```

It works fine if i assign text directly to "desc". But i want it to work when received from server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use triple quotes string in Kotlin to achieve this like

```
val myString = """this is one line
                 *this is another line"""
```

If having them as a variable instead you could probably do something like

```
val s = """$var1 
          *$var2
```

Sorry can't test it myself at the moment but hope that can be helpful somehow.